# Parameterized logic including module instantiation and so on

Tags: verilog, system-verilog

I want to enable logic, module instantiation etc.. with module's parameter like this:

```
module mymodule #(
  parameter FEATURE_ENABLE  = 0
)(
  input   logic          clk,
  ...
);

if (FEATURE_ENABLE==1) begin
 logic feature;
 modulea modulea_instance (
   .clk (clk),
   ...
 );

  for (h=0;h<=20;h=h+1) begin:forloopinstance
    always_comb begin
      if (sys_reset) begin
        ind_type[h] = UNKNOWN;
      end else begin
        ind_type[h] = ZERO;
      end
    end
  end

end

endmodule
```

It seems Modelsim doesn't support it and Xilinx Vivado does support it but not completely.

**What's the best practice for enabling part of the logic with parameter?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code uses the 2005 version of the Verilog standard - IEEE 1364-2005. IEEE 1364-2005 took away the need to use `generate` and `endgenerate` statements. Personally, I really don't see the point of doing that. A `generate` construct is a bit out-of-the-ordinary and so deserves the extra fanfare provided by the `generate` and `endgenerate` statements. How about adding them anyway:

```
module mymodule #(
  parameter FEATURE_ENABLE  = 0
)(
  input   logic          clk
);

  generate
    if (FEATURE_ENABLE==1) begin
      logic feature;
      modulea modulea_instance (
       .clk (clk)
      );
    end
  endgenerate

endmodule
```

https://www.edaplayground.com/x/4k86

I'm sure Modelsim will support it, what error message are you getting?

Comment: Actually my problem came from modelsim that adds a parent `genblk1` for all the signals under the implicit generate block... But I found that thanks to you. Thank you!

Comment: Can I use an `always_comb` in a `for loop` inside the `conditional block`? I edited the code in my question. It's recognized by Vivado not by Riviera/Modelsim.

Comment: @Alexis_FR_JP Yes. You can put anything inside a `generate`-`endgenerate` that can go between `module`-`endmodule`.